# Create Community User through REST API

Tags: rest-api, community, nforce

I am using the [nForce](https://github.com/kevinohara80/nforce) library with node.js.
Everything seems to be right and we perform CRUD on the Case object.

However when we try to create a User using an external account with **"Delegated External User Administrator"** permission, the API returns the following message:

> {errorCode: "INVALID_FIELD", messageBody: "No such column 'profileid'
>   on sobject of type User", statusCode: 400, $get: function, $save:
>   function…}

This is the data we sent to `https://<org domain>/services/data/v30.0/sobjects/user` using `HTTP POST`:

```
{
   "Username": "testapi@test.com",
   "LastName": "API",
   "Email": "testapi@test.com",
   "Alias": "testapi",
   "TimeZoneSidKey" : "America/Los_Angeles",
   "LocaleSidKey" : "en_US",
   "EmailEncodingKey" : "ISO-8859-1",
   "ProfileId" : "00e90000001a88W",
   "LanguageLocaleKey" : "en_US",
   "ContactId": "00390000013gwDS"
 }
```

How come there is no 'profileid' column? I can create a user using an internal admin account with the same set of data on the  REST API.

Can a user with "Delegated External User Administrator" permission create a new external user through the REST API?

Comment: can the user do the delegated administration using the UI?

Comment: User can do delegated administration through SF Community Portal

Comment: When I use a system admin account to login and create user using the same set of data, everything goes right. However a delegated external admin cannot do so.

Comment: Can someone help me on this issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you allowed the delegated user permissions to manage that profile? See https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=networks_DPUA.htm for the example guide

Comment: We have already allowed the profile to be managed by delegated user admin. The delegated user admin account can also create new user through Salesforce community web page, but not through REST API

Comment: I don't know whether you resolved this or not, but there's an example of how to use REST to create new users in one of the tutorials in the [Security WorkBook](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/workbook_security/workbook_security.pdf). Perhaps if you went through that using a Community User as the test case instead of a Standard User, you'd be able to resolve your issue.

Comment: How is it coming?  Did you find the problem?  I was wondering whether <org domain> in your example is the regular domain for licensed users, or the portal URL.

Comment: I know this sounds completely unrelated but I had to build a user via APEX and couldn't use the pre-built command for it due to some conflicts with a NPSP version they were running.

Eventually the problem was the owner of the Account record the Contact of the User was associated with needed to have more permissions than the Guest User was permitted. The errors completely threw me off and I happened on that by accident. Its worth a try temporarily changing the owner to an Admin Profile user and seeing if the creation works.

Answer (score 1):

If it's an issue, why don't you create a custom REST apex class?

here's a sample class and method:

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/UserOperation/*')
global without sharing class RESTUserController {

    @HttpPost   
    global static String CreateNewUser(String Username,String LastName,String Email,String Alias,String TimeZoneSidKey,String LocaleSidKey,String EmailEncodingKey,String ProfileId,String LanguageLocaleKey,String ContactId) {
        User newUser = new User();
        newUser.Username = Username;
        newUser.LastName = LastName;
        newUser.Email = Email;
        newUser.Alias = Alias;
        newUser.TimeZoneSidKey = TimeZoneSidKey;
        newUser.LocaleSidKey = LocaleSidKey;
        newUser.EmailEncodingKey = EmailEncodingKey;
        newUser.ProfileId = ProfileId;
        newUser.LanguageLocaleKey = LanguageLocaleKey;
        newUser.ContactId = ContactId;
        insert newUser;
        return 'User Created! Id Is: ' + newUser.Id ;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, i'm think, error-message is clearly describe the problem. External customer don't have a permissions to see the profile object..

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_profile.htm#topic-title